# send udp packets from a specific ip

Tags: python, udp

I need to simulate some udp device that sends udp packets with a specific ip (for example 10.20.30.40).

Does it possible to do it? because in all the udp server examples i see that ip is 127.0.0.1.

I prefer to do it with python but other ways will be welcomed too.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do that with Python is by using `scapy`. Example:

```
import scapy.all
packet = scapy.all.Ether() / scapy.all.IP(src='10.20.30.40') / scapy.all.UDP()
packet.show2()
```

The `show2()` method would show you how the packet was set, among that the source IP:

[image]

Then you can send the packet using, for instance, `scapy.all.sendp(packet)`. For starters you could send the packet and use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on the destination machine to see if it is reaching there as you would expect.

Be mindful though about faking the source IP in the wild, it could cause you trouble.